# iText7 deep formField hierarchies aren't handled correctly

Tags: itext, itext7

iText 7.0.0

i'm not sure if it's a feature of LiveCycle/XFA or a convention adopted by our forms team, but a lot of the form field qualified names end up looking like:

```
form[0].someForm_page1[0].table1[0].row1[0].cell1[0].Text[0]
form[0].someForm_page1[0].table1[0].row1[0].cell1[0].Text[1]
```

when merging (PdfDocument.copyTo...including PdfPageFormCopier) only the immediate parent of a page's /Widgets are copied over (although i mention XFA above, this behavior occurs for non hybrid forms as well).

```
PdfDocument src = createForRead("someForm.pdf");
PdfDocument merged = createForWrite("merged.pdf");
src.copyPagesTo(1, src.getNumberOfPages(), merged, new PdfPageFormCopier());
merged.close();
src.close();
```

results in fields that look like

```
 cell1[0].Text[0]
 cell1[0].Text[1]
```

or worse, for a case like this

```
page1.section1.Text1
page2.section1.Text1
```

not building the full hierarchy may cause unique fields to become non-unique

```
section1.Text1
section1.Text1
```

in SmartMode, things seem to be a little bit worse still (this one seems to be fixed in 7.0.1-20162707!)

```
page1.Text1
page2.Text1
```

merges to

```
page1.Text1
page1.Text1
```

Comment: Please share a sample PDF to reproduce the issue.

Comment: FYI - this is sortof fixed in 7.0.1-SNAPSHOT as of Aug-08-16 (commit 4ab26ed) and resolution is being tracked in iText JIRA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in iText 7.0.1